# qemu + centos 7 - cpu tuning in not available on this host

Tags: kvm-switch, qemu

I am running OpenNebula on Centos 7 hosts - one host is fully operating the other two says:

error: unsupported configuration: CPU tuning is not available on this host

I've got through some git code where this is mentioned in qemu_cgroup - but everything on those hosts seems same except kernel which is little bit different on running host:

3.10.0-123.6.3.el7.x86_64

but on those two nodes is

3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

We had the same problem, and we solved changing the kernel to linux-image-server or linux-generic.

Comment: Please be specific.

Comment: Why/how did this fix your problem? Please expand on your answer.

Comment: For me this solved my problem also - this error dissapeared - I've used precompiled kernel from OVH for which I don't know how it was built.